# Анимация перемещения точки по траектории в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, анимация

Есть такой код рисования графика.

Заголовочный файл:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui>
#include <cmath>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
    QList <int> bufer;
    QTimer * startanimation;
    QPainter * painter;

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    void MakeData(int value);

public slots:
    void paintEventWarm();
    void painEventPath();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

Файл с реализацией:

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent) {

    QPushButton * button1 = new QPushButton(this);

    button1 ->setText("OK");
    startanimation= new QTimer (this);
    startanimation->setInterval(1000);


    connect(button1,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(painEventPath()));
    connect(startanimation,SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(paintEventWarm()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){    
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) 
{
    painter = new QPainter(this);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QPen BlackPen (Qt::black);
    BlackPen.setWidth(1);

    QPen BluePen (Qt::blue);
    BluePen.setWidth(2);

    QPoint p1,p2;

    int sh = width()/2;

    p1.setX(0);
    p1.setY(sh);

    p2.setX(width());
    p2.setY(sh);

    painter->setPen(BlackPen);
    painter->drawRect(0, 0, width(), height());

    painter->setPen(BluePen);

    // Строим синусоиду
    p2.setX(0);
    p2.setY(sh);

    painter->setPen(BluePen);
    for (int i = 0; i<bufer.size();i+=2) {
        p1 = p2;
        p2.setX(bufer.at(i));
        p2.setY (sh+bufer.at(i+1));
        painter->drawLine(p1,p2);

    }
}

void MainWindow::MakeData(int value){
    float x, y, point_x, point_y;

    int mas_y;

    const int size_x = width();
    const int size_y = height()/6;

    bufer.clear();

    for (point_x = 0; point_x < size_x; point_x+=3) {
        x = 30*point_x/size_x;

        switch(value){
            case 0: break;
            case 1: {
                y = sin(x);
                mas_y = 4;
                break;
            };
            case 2: {
                y = 2*pow(x,2)-14*x;
                mas_y = 70;
                break;
            };
            case 3: {
                y = tan(x);
                mas_y = 500;
                break;
            };
            case 4: {
                y = atan(x);
                mas_y = 4;
                break;
            }
        };

        point_y = (size_y-(y+1)*size_y/mas_y);
        bufer << point_x << point_y;
    }
}

void MainWindow::painEventPath() {    
    QString str = "value1";
    MakeData(str.remove(0,5).left(5).toInt());
    this->repaint();
    startanimation->start();
}

void MainWindow::paintEventWarm() {
    QPoint p1,p2;
    p2.setX(0);
    p2.setY(width()/2);
    QPen RedPen (Qt::red);
    RedPen.setWidth(2);

    painter->setPen(RedPen);
    for (int i = 0; i<bufer.size(); i+=2){
        p1 = p2;
        p2.setX(bufer.at(i));
        p2.setY (width()/2+bufer.at(i+1));
        painter->drawPoint(p1);
    }
    startanimation->stop();    
}
```

Идея приложения: По нажатию на кнопку рисуется график (эта часть работает).

Затем на графике появляется красная точка и плавно ездит туда-обратно по графику.

С анимацией точки как раз проблемы.

За анимацию по задумке должна отвечать функция `paintEventWarm()`, которая вызывается каждый раз при переполнении таймера, но у меня вылетает ошибка "Программа неожиданно завершилась".

Помогите правильно реализовать анимацию красной точки, спасибо.

Обновление: 
Функцию `paintEventWarm()` переписал следующим образом:

```
void MainWindow::paintEventWarm(){
animationpoint.setX(bufer.at(1+count));
animationpoint.setY(width()/2+bufer.at(1+count));
count++;
update();
}
```

Где `count` — переменная типа `int`. Вот что мне выдала ОС:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отсюда вопрос: Как правильно рассчитывать положение точки?

Comment: Вы опять вылетаете за границу буфера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вылетает у вас из-за вот этого кода:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bufer.size(); i+=2) {
    //...
    p2.setY (width()/2+bufer.at(i+1)); // <- i+1
    //...
```

Здесь вы выходите за пределы списка.

Но, в принципе, подход неверный.

Вам надо перенести код отрисовки точки в метод paintEvent, а в методе
paintEventWarm просто расчитывать новое положение точки:

```
void paintEvent() {
    // Отрисовываем положение точки
}

void paintEventWarm() {
    // расчитываем новое положение точки
    update(); // Запрос перерисовки нового положения точки
}
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH это же другой вопрос, ну так и задайте его отдельно.