# Qt анимация движения точки по заданной траектории

Tags: c++, qt

Суть вопроса в том, что я не совсем понимаю как вообще сделать анимацию движения точки по траектории. Был уже похожий вопрос тут [Анимация перемещения точки по траектории в Qt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/991009/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-qt), но так и не понятно как мне это осуществить. Вообще задача состоит из того, что нам нужно запустить анимацию движения точки по заданной траектории (к примеру синуса) и это траектория должна оставлять след когда точка пройдет по ней. Подскажите пожалуйста, как в qt это можно сделать.
 Хотелось бы использовать QGraphicsScene если это возможно.

Собственно, я сделал через QGraphicsScene отрисовку анимации движения точки, мне осталось сделать отрисовку траектории ее передвижения. Была мысль записывать в условный QVector vec каждую точку, а потом отрисовывать ее через MainWindow::paintEvent, но к сожалению ничего не выходит. Возможно есть мысли как сделать отрисовку траектории движения точки. Ниже код 
H:

```
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>

#include <QTimer>
#include <QVector>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE;

class FalCirc: public QGraphicsEllipseItem{
public:
    FalCirc(int xps, int yps);
    void advance(int phase);
   QVector<QPoint> vec;
private:
    double tim;
    int a;
    int b;
    int tn;
    double tk, t;
    double x0, y0, x1, y1;
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene* scene;
    QTimer* anim_timer;
    FalCirc* f;

    // QWidget interface
protected slots:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

CPP:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <cmath>

#define CIRCLE_SIZE 5
#define CIRCLE_X 400
#define CIRCLE_Y 200
#define pi  3.14

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 800, 600, this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    scene->addRect(scene->sceneRect());

   f = new FalCirc(CIRCLE_X+100,CIRCLE_Y+100);
//   f = new FalCirc(CIRCLE_X+(R*(m+1)*cos(m*1)-h*cos((m+1)*1)),CIRCLE_Y+(R*(m+1)*sin(m*1)-h*sin((m+1)*1)));
    scene->addItem(f);

   anim_timer = new QTimer(this);
   connect(anim_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),scene, SLOT(advance()));   
   anim_timer->start(1000/60);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event)
    QPainter p(this); // Создаём новый объект рисовальщика
    p.setPen(QPen(Qt::red,1,Qt::SolidLine)); // Настройки рисования
   p.drawEllipse(this->f->x(),this->f->y(),20,20);
}


FalCirc::FalCirc(int xps,int yps)
{
    setRect(400,300,20,20);
    setPos(400,200);
    a=50;
    b=75;
    tn=0;
    tk= 4 * pi;
    x0 = CIRCLE_X +100;
    y0 = CIRCLE_Y +100;
}

void FalCirc::advance(int phase)
{

    if(phase){
     t+=0.01;
     x1=(a+b)*cos(t)-a*cos(((a+b)*t)/a);
     y1=(a+b)*sin(t)-a*sin(((a+b)*t)/a);
     vec.push_back(QPoint(x1,y1));
     this->setRect(x1,y1,5,5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Уточните в вопросе что собираетесь использовать, ведь в `qt` это можно сделать разными способами, например через графическую сцену или отрисовкой через `opengl`

Comment: Желательно без opengl, было бы не плохо это сделать через QGraphicsScene

Comment: ну так и напишите это в вопросе

Comment: Спасибо за замечание

Comment: Вам интересна математическая составляющая или Вы застряли с другим?

Comment: Вам надо по таймеру или в отдельно потоке очищать ваш "канвас" и рисовать вашу точку с новыми координатами.

Comment: И математическая часть тоже. Но больше интересно как именно можно перемещать по какой-либо траектории (с анимацией) объект. Возможно есть шаблон какой-то? У меня есть уравнение графика, а вот как перемещать по графику точку не понятно. Я так понял можно это сделать используя qgraphicsitem, но как?

Comment: перемещать точку или фигуру или любой QGraphicsItem  можно функцией `void QGraphicsItem::setTransform(const QTransform &matrix, bool combine = false)`

Comment: Обновил вопрос, так и не смог разобраться с отрисовкой траектории перемещения точки

Comment: Зачем использовать paintEvent() главного окна? Вся отрисовка реализована в сцене. Для того, чтобы передвинуть точку, достаточно вызвать у объекта "точка" метод setPos() и передать новые координаты. Линии сами по себе создаваться не будут. Это отдельный объект сцены (QGraphicsLineItem), который должен создать разработчик. По таймеру рисуешь линию от старой позиции до новой, и все.

Comment: Ого, действительно помогло. Спасибо большое. Теперь все решено!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант анимации движения точки из верхнего угла по диагонали (бесконечно)
mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

protected slots:
    void onTimeout();

private:
    QGraphicsScene* _scene;
    QGraphicsView* _view;
    QTimer* _timer;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem* _point;

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    _scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 800, 600, this);
    _scene->addRect(_scene->sceneRect());

    _view = new QGraphicsView;
    _view->setScene(_scene);

    QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(_view);

    QWidget* mainWidget = new QWidget;
    mainWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);

    this->setCentralWidget(mainWidget);

    _point = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 10, 10);
    _scene->addItem(_point);

   _timer = new QTimer(this);
   connect(_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::onTimeout);
   _timer->start(100);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::onTimeout()
{
    QPointF oldPos = _point->pos();
    QPointF newPos = QPointF(_point->pos().x() + 10, _point->pos().y() + 10);

    _point->setPos(newPos);

    QGraphicsLineItem* line = new QGraphicsLineItem (QLineF(oldPos, newPos));

    _scene->addItem(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем получился такой код. Спасибо всем из коментов, особенно [e-n-shirokov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/273300/e-n-shirokov")!

.h

```
        class FalCirc: public QGraphicsEllipseItem{
    public:
        FalCirc(QGraphicsScene* parent);
        void advance(int phase);
       QGraphicsScene* main_widg;
    private:
        double t;
        double x0, y0, x1, y1;
        double R;
        double m;
        double h;
    };

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~MainWindow();

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        QGraphicsScene* scene;
        QTimer* anim_timer;
        FalCirc* f;
    };
```

.Cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 800, 600, this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    scene->addRect(scene->sceneRect());

   f = new FalCirc(scene);
   scene->addItem(f);
   anim_timer = new QTimer(this);
   connect(anim_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),scene, SLOT(advance()));   
   anim_timer->start(1000/60);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

FalCirc::FalCirc(QGraphicsScene* parent)
{
   main_widg = parent;
   setRect(400,300,20,20);
    t=0; R=100; m=0.2;  h=10; 
}

void FalCirc::advance(int phase)
{
    if(phase){
     t+=0.1;
     x1=((R*(m+1))*(cos(m*t)))-(h*(cos((m+1)*t)));
     y1=((R*(m+1))*(sin(m*t)))-(h*(sin((m+1)*t)));
     x0=x1;
     y0=y1;
     main_widg->addLine(x0+400,y0+300,x1+400,y1+300);
     this->setPos(x1,y1);
     }
}
```

Все заработало, и вот результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]